# How to ignore inserting records from a table to another table when both table field has same value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables which have names and emails. Now I want to merge these tables into a new table without duplicate records. I want to use email fields for avoiding duplicate values in both tables. I heard INSERT IGNORE query is using for inserting values into a table without affecting existing records. How to write INSERT IGNORE query to check email field for duplication checking. If anyone knows other methods are also welcome.

```
table1:
fid fname   email
--- -----   -----
1   Balaji  balaji@email.com
2   xxxxx    xxxxx@email.com
3   Bala    bala@email.com

table2:

gid gname  gemail
--- -----  ------
1   Bala   bala@email.com
2   vinoth vinoth@email.com
```

### Expected result:

```
table3:
-------
id name   email
-- ----   -----
1   Balaji  balaji@email.com
2   xxxxx    xxxxx@email.com
3   Bala    bala@email.com
4   vinoth vinoth@email.com
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: did you found solution for this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/is-there-any-free-extension-available-for-designing-products-label-or-cover-in-m/%22Here%22? , if so please help me with complete code, can you join here : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42832/magento-discuss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL support `UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY` but in order to work, you need to add a `unique` constraint on the table you want to insert.

Assuming `Table3` is the name of your new table. You need to add constraint first,

```
ALTER TABLE Table3 ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (name, email)
```

and you can now have unique records on the new table, to merge the previous table,

```
INSERT INTO table3(name, email)
SELECT name, email 
FROM
(
    SELECT fid id, fname name, email FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT gid id, gname name, gemail email FROM Table1
) s
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c5004/1)
- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

---

An alternative solution without using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. is to use `UNION` (*without ALL*) and assumes that `Table3.ID` is set as auto-increment

```
INSERT INTO table3(name, email)
SELECT name, email 
FROM
(
    SELECT fname name, email FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT gname name, gemail email FROM Table2
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/753db/1)